# Linux full disk encryption passphrase in sync with local user password

Tags: linux, security, fde

I'm trying to setup a Linux FDE where the passphrase is in sync with /etc/shadow file, similar to Mac's FileVault which uses the user's login password as the encryption pass phrase. Is it possible to have such a setup with LUKS ?

Comment: is your system really storing passwd info in /etc/passwd? I've been under the impression that no modern distro has done that in a decade, and instead use /etc/shadow to store encrypted (or hashed?) passwords exclusively, but because so much softare already read User info out of passwd, they did not want to change the existing layout/content. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_password

Comment: @FrankThomas: Actually I wanted to say "... in sync with local user password". Edited my question appropriately.